# Cannot access an IIS container from browser - Docker

Tags: docker, iis, windows-server-2016

Windows Version: Windows Server 2016

Docker for Windows Version: 18.09.0

[image]

I try to follow the steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-images

I have a Docker file on c:\Build:

```
FROM microsoft/iis
RUN echo "Hello World - Dockerfile" > c:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.html
```

Please note that I have tried using `FROM microsoft/iis:10.0.14393.206` as well

So, I ran using powershell with admin privilege:

```
docker build -t imagename c:\Build
```

Then I ran:

```
docker run -d -p 8000:80 --name container imagename ping -t localhost
```

[image]

All of the above steps are fine, but I cannot access the website,

I tried every combination like:
the ip address from ipconfig:8000 or 80; the ip address from inspect :8000 / 80.
Please note that I had also set up Firewall to allow port 8000 as well

[image]

But it all failed.

Then, I went to the Internet and found that I can actucally call the bash. therefore, I ran exec, however, there was something strange happened:

[image]

I am not sure whether it means the container is not worknig?
But the inspect and container ls show it should be working.

fyi
network:
[image]

inspect container:
[image]
[image]
[image]

I really cannot find any solution from the Internet

Any advice would be helpful, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I got it to work with the following configuration below, and with remote IIS access. Make sure that firewall is not blocking docker to your local ip's. Also, the app in our case is part of a website, so we need to use Webadministration to deploy it as an application to make it work. Logs and everything else is working now and we have a running sample.

I been playing as well with the docker container and I been having similar issues deploying. I am using a server core image instead as it has full fledge powershell on it, but I have my dockerfile defined like this to build the image at the moment doing tests because the application seems to not start. the app is not on core yet but will migrate to it soon to make the working image smaller. Another thing to note from this sample, the application pool is not getting created even tho its being defined on my commands. With this you can connect remotely with the iis remote management tool and check how is the server setup up to this point inside the docker.:

```
##Pull the base image to use
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis
#Enable verbose output in case of errors
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';"]
#install all needed features of IIS
RUN Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Server -IncludeManagementTools ;\
    Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Basic-Auth ;\
    Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Windows-Auth ;\
    Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Net-Ext45 ;\
    Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-ISAPI-Ext ;\
    Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-ISAPI-Filter ;\
    Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-WHC ;\
    Install-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-45-ASPNET ; \
    Install-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45 ;\
    Install-WindowsFeature -Name Web-Mgmt-Service ;\
    Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Mgmt-Tools ;\
    Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Mgmt-Compat ;\
    Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Scripting-Tools ;\
    Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ManagementService /all ;\
    ##Still inside the same run command, enable remote management for IIS on docker
    New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WebManagement\Server -Name EnableRemoteManagement -Value 1 -Force ;\
    Get-Service -Name WMSVC | Start-Service ;\
    Set-Service –Name WMSVC –StartupType 'Automatic' ;\
    ##In the same run Command add the user and password for IIS remote management
        net user myuser superP@ss123 /ADD ;\
        net localgroup administrators myuser /add

    COPY . myapp
    RUN New-WebAppPool myapp
#The configStore is an application of a website, so add it as such to the service
RUN Import-Module WebAdministration; Get-Module ;\
    New-Item 'IIS:Sites\Default Web Site\myapp' -physicalPath 'c:\myapp' -ApplicationPool 'myapp' -type 'Application'

EXPOSE 51329 80
```

The other question I have no answer is if we can actually assign a memory size to the docker images on creation and not just the standard by the owner.

Comment: I guess you can assign memory size of a container on creation (Docker Run)

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user-memory-constraints

Likewise, you are asked to do so when creating an AWS ECS instance

Comment: I just got it to work. The problem was that our app is designed to work as an iis application inside a main website. after doing some changes, I got it to work. I also made adjustments to some of the scripts so I have remote access to iis and make changes. Now all tracelogs are worjking and are visible inside the docker image. I am going to update the script here for you to see how I currently have it. Also I will check on that post and try again the memory thing

Comment: Mind if I ask: can you access the website from another machine in the same network? I find the port mapping over nat does not work as I expected, I guess we do need bridge/custom network... but I cannot create one. Tbh, Docker 
 in Windows Server has too little support and information... Unlike Linux or even Docker for Windows (not for Windows server >=2016)

Comment: Just locally. This configuration is for local machines as we are trying to do offline development. If you are trying to do the server sharing you need to grant the docker ip and port privileges to the firewall, and you should be able to manage the Nat directly on docker through compose or the dockerfile

Comment: Hey @Near just in case, we found out that you can use Docker-compose to make the build process of your own networking for docker a lot easier with the newer drivers. You can use ICS or MacVlan drivers to build the internal network for your users to reach from the server and that is probably the easiet way to configure it. Of course you can use the dockerfile just to do network configuration and it should/would work the same way. I will add a separate answer if possible once we have the completed prototype for you to try it out if you still working on this

Comment: Thx @Truesky, I don't mind to know more about this. I have been building Docker in Windows Server 2016 in an EC2 AWS m3 instance. The cloud operator of my company guessed the reason why we are not able to create a bridge/custom network is AWS blocked the option. So... we tried another way by using AWS ECS instance but we are still open for suggestion. btw I notice one thing: when we create an AWS ECS instance, it requires us to input parameter for Docker run and it states clearly that a Windows container can only use "default" network for connection... but maybe it is the reason?

Comment: Hey @Near possibly. I read something about unsupported network commands on a doc from MS. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/container-networking/architecture     See if that gives you a better clue on how to set it up. I'll dig some more later to see if I can provide you with a better answer and update this one. But I think at this point you can complete this story as the main intent is completed and possibly open a separate thread to point this one and the new question

Comment: The posted question is in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54995644/port-mapping-in-windows-server-2016-docker

Answer (score 0):

After a month, I have another way to get to the container's IIS...

I am going to post the answer here, in case someone encounters similar issues

The setup greatly relates to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/containerstuff/2017/02/14/manage-iis-on-a-container-with-the-iis-admin-console/

The difference is:

To fully install IIS in a container, use the following DockerFile:

(There are some steps missed in the document, you cannot have wmsvc and IIS admin services installed without the following lines included in the Dockerfile below)

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.6.2

RUN powershell -Command Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Server -IncludeManagementTools

RUN powershell -Command Add-WindowsFeature web-webserver

RUN powershell -Command Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Basic-Auth

RUN powershell -Command Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Windows-Auth

RUN powershell -Command Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Net-Ext45

RUN powershell -Command Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Asp-Net45

RUN powershell -Command Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-ISAPI-Ext

RUN powershell -Command Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-ISAPI-Filter

RUN powershell -Command Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-WHC

RUN powershell -Command Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Mgmt-Tools

RUN powershell -Command Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Mgmt-Compat

RUN powershell -Command Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Mgmt-Service

RUN powershell -Command Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Scripting-Tools

RUN powershell Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ManagementService /all
```

1. `Docker run` the image with -it / `Docker attach` the container
2. start container's powershell by typing `powershell`
3. running `Get-service` to see if IISadmin, w3svc and wmsvc are there.

It will show that wmsvc is not started (strangely, even I run `sc config wmsvc start=auto` in DockerFile still does not work)

4. `net start` the service
5. use host's IIS to connect to the container's IIS (similar to the step given by the link above)

It should be able to connect to the container from host and now you have successfully implemented a web application in a container.

PS. Note that firewall may block the remote management process

Comment: and surely, I can now get to the container hosted website from host's browser