# running local webpage using a docker IIS container

Tags: docker, iis

Running Docker for windows to host a local IIS to test a webpage, using [the default windows IIS dockerpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5yTF.png)

I am not sure what part to change in my dockerfile that allows me to run my webpage. Simply editing the COPY command in the dockerfile is what I thought I would need to change, but that isnt the case. What do I need to do to have it run a different html file instead of the default windows IIS page?

EDIT : Was able to find the open container by searching wwwroot in my C:, and I copy and pasted my hello world index.html page and was able to get it running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could follow below steps:

Create a Dockerfile with your website

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis

RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command Remove-Item -Recurse C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*

WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot

COPY content/ .
```

You can then build and run the Docker image:

```
$ docker build -t iis-site .
$ docker run -d -p 8000:80 --name my-running-site iis-site
```

There is no need to specify an ENTRYPOINT in your Dockerfile since the microsoft/iis base image already includes an entrypoint application that monitors the status of the IIS World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC).

With the current release, you can't use http://localhost to browse your site from the container host. This is because of a known behavior in WinNAT, and will be resolved in future. Until that is addressed, you need to use the IP address of the container.

Once the container starts, you'll need to finds its IP address so that you can connect to your running container from a browser. You use the docker inspect command to do that:

```
docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress }}" my-running-site
```

You will see an output similar to this:

```
172.28.103.186
```

You can connect the running container using the IP address and configured port, http://172.28.103.186:8000 in the example shown.
In addition to static content, IIS can run other workloads including but not limited to ASP.NET, ASP.NET Core, NodeJS, PHP, and Apache Tomcat.

For more detail you could refer below links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/deployment/docker-aspnetmvc

https://mcpmag.com/articles/2019/11/20/iis-on-windows-server-containers.aspx

[Cannot access an IIS container from browser - Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53590787/cannot-access-an-iis-container-from-browser-docker)

Comment: Super helpful thanks so much - I am just unclear on where I am supposed to put my html files and the like when I am trying to run this site locally?

Comment: @mchammerhead you could try to put that file in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.html as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53590787/cannot-access-an-iis-container-from-browser-docker) post. If the post helps you to resolve your issue then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Comment: - I just had to find the right folder in C:/Docker ! I was able to run my hello world index.html page so I think I should be able to figure it out from here! Thanks much. I maked your suggestion as answer

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the docker file like below after which it worked perfectly

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis
RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command Remove-Item -Recurse C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
RUN mkdir -p content
COPY . content/
```